# Society that doesn't know violence, where they live in trees?

Tags: story-identification

I am half-remembering a book that I read probably 30 years ago about this society where violence is unknown and I think they lived in trees?

I have a distinct memory of someone being threatened toward the story's end with an unfamiliar "triangular object" (a gun).

Can anyone help me remember the name if the book? I would love for my kids to read it!

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Please try to add anything that may help identification. What was the cover like? What language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

Comment: Well, I don't think it's Integral Trees, by Larry Niven.

Comment: I don't suppose it's the same book being described in [this post](http://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/735309-ya-fantasy-society-in-trees-solved-i-think-s)? Also, it would be great if you could remember any more details - do have a read through the [checklists](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/31394) [here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9336/31394) to see if anything jogs your memory.

Comment: Sounds a bit like Green Sky books... which is in the question @Rand links from Goodreads.  Yes, more details please.

Comment: It might conceivably be Alan Dean Foster's *Midworld* (but it's decades since I read it, and my recollection is hazy).

Comment: Sounds like a book I read once. I remember the main character, a girl, saying to her brother at one point that she'd like to "dead him" (using "dead" as a verb because they had no word for "kill") and her family reacting in complete shock. And there was a society of ground-dwellers too, and they did remember the word for "kill", and the MC met a ground-dwelling girl around her age... any of this familiar? (Unfortunately I read the book in school, also around 25-30 years ago, and have long since forgotten title or author.)

Comment: Just checked out the e-book from the library, and while I didn't remember all the details correctly, the book I was thinking of is *definitely* "Below the Root", the first book in Zilpha Keatley Snyder's "Green Sky" trilogy.

Comment: That is it! Below the Root. Zilpha Keatley Snyder is such a great author. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

Submitted since comments can get deleted, and it's been almost 2 years.

[Joe White](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/3428/joe-white) identified the book as "[Below the Root](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?3576)" in a couple of comments.

> Sounds like a book I read once. I remember the main character, a girl,
> saying to her brother at one point that she'd like to "dead him"
> (using "dead" as a verb because they had no word for "kill") and her
> family reacting in complete shock. And there was a society of
> ground-dwellers too, and they did remember the word for "kill", and
> the MC met a ground-dwelling girl around her age... any of this
> familiar? (Unfortunately I read the book in school, also around 25-30
> years ago, and have long since forgotten title or author.)
>
> Just checked out the e-book from the library, and while I didn't
> remember all the details correctly, the book I was thinking of is
> definitely "Below the Root", the first book in Zilpha Keatley Snyder's
> "Green Sky" trilogy.

The questioner [Laura](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/74520/laura) accepted the ID in a comment.

> That is it! Below the Root. Zilpha Keatley Snyder is such a great
> author. Thanks so much!

Comment: Whilst I appreciate you going through old story id answers to provide an answer if it was accepted in the comments could you at either a) add more information than just the comments or b) if this is just going to be info from the comments make it a community wiki answer.